# ActionBar displays only text

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I would want to have an actionable that has a custom background, and two icons. One for the app icon and the other replacing the text name of the app.

Currently , for some reason , the only thing that is displayed is text and an invisible margin at the top :

[image]

- I'm using support library (v7) ,my minSdk is 9.

manifest :

```
...
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" android:name=".myPagerActivity" /> 
...
```

Comment: What have you done so far in your code?

Comment: `<activity
               android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
            android:name=".myPagerActivity" />`
That's the only thing.. But it at least should show some background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `AppCompat` version 21 and it is normal.

The Action Bar follows the material design guidelines and uses a `Toolbar`.
As you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

```
The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is 
    discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.
```

It is the reason because you are displaying only the test in your Activity.

You can customize your Toolbar. Something like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">

    <!-- your custom views here -->

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your `AppCompatActivity`:

```
Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(actionBar);

//Customize your views here...
```

Finally you have to use a appcompat theme like `.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

Replace your ActionBar by a Toolbar.[Toolbar](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/toolbars.html) are easy to customize.

Comment: But my min sdk is 9 as already stated.  Toolbar is 11+ as far as I know..
Also , more importantly , I'm using ViewPager which as far as I know can only be implemented with actionBar/AppCompatActivity
Thanks

Comment: A question. Do you really need sdk 9? it reaches only 5% of all android users. With a higher minimum sdk it give other users a better experience. I style.xml you can set a style with.NoActionBar. then you add a toolbar in your layout.

Comment: I know but unfortunately I have to use 9.. Certain constraints.

Comment: Then you should try styling the actionbar via styles.xml like Anmol Srivastava said

Comment: The minSdk of Toolbar is 7

Comment: that's weird.. I was always getting an error saying I need minimum 11.
The same is stated in google android website..

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

Did you try it with the support library?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define a custom theme and style the action bar.
Check https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

You can change almost all the attributes associated with the action bar.